# git deleted files shows in red, how to remove them

Tags: git

After I deleted files from my directory on git status command from git bash cli I'm getting list of all deleted files in red like

**deleted:  MyProject/commands/fileone.txt**

Now when I'm using git status command I'm getting huge list of these deleted files.

Which command to use to remove this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "add" deleted files for the next commit using `git add -u`

Comment: @user1765862, also you can `git rm --cached` them after the fact to remove them from the index.

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the files using `git rm`, you need to make a new commit: `git commit -m "Removed files"`